# SQL phpMyAdmin: List teams with more away wins than home wins

Tags: mysql

I have a database called Football with the following tables: Footballers, Teams, Managers, Matches. I'm trying to list the teams that have more away wins than home wins. A home win is where a team is the home team in a match and the number of home goals exceeds the number of away goals – the opposite being the case for away wins.

I can display the number of home wins using:

```
SELECT T.TeamName, COUNT(*) AS HomeWins
FROM Teams T, Matches M
WHERE M.HomeTeamID = T.TeamID AND M.HomeGoals > M.AwayGoals
```

and similarly get the number of away wins.

When I try to put the two together to get the teams with more away than home wins I'm getting an error, I've tried a few different ways including:

```
SELECT T.TeamName
FROM Teams T, Matches M
WHERE M.HomeTeamID = T.TeamID
HAVING COUNT (M.HomeGoals > M.AwayGoals) > COUNT(M.AwayGoals > M.HomeGoals)

SELECT T.TeamName
FROM Teams T, Matches M
WHERE M.HomeTeamID = T.TeamID AND (COUNT (M.HomeGoals > M.AwayGoals) > COUNT(M.AwayGoals > M.HomeGoals)

SELECT T.TeamName
WHERE
  (COUNT DISTINCT(TeamID) FROM Teams T, Matches M WHERE M.HomeTeamID = T.TeamID AND M.HomeGoals > M.AwayGoals) >
  (COUNT DISTINCT(TeamID) FROM Teams T, Matches M WHERE M.AwayTeamID = T.TeamID AND M.HomeGoals < M.AwayGoals)
```

None of these are working. I know I'm probably missing something very basic here but I'd really appreciate some insight as I can't seem to get this to work.

Comment: what error do u get?

Comment: you cannot directly use count in and clause..you have to write select count('xyz') from abc ... in the and clause..try this and tell me

Comment: Can you please share your tables' structure?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can read up on how to [ask] a question and create a [mcve]. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Tables' structure: 
Teams (TeamID INT NOT NULL , TeamName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, City VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, ManagerID INT)

Matches (MatchID INT NOT NULL , HomeTeamID INT NOT NULL, AwayTeamID INT NOT NULL, MatchDate DATE NOT NULL, HomeGoals INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, AwayGoals INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0)

Footballers (FootballerID INT NOT NULL , FootballerName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, TeamID INT NOT NULL,  Position VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, WeeklySalary DECIMAL(7,2), TransferFee DECIMAL (10,2))

Managers (ManagerID INT NOT NULL , ManagerName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, WeeklySalary DECIMAL(6,2))

Comment: Zaki Mustafa, I tried the following: SELECT T.TeamName
FROM Teams T, Matches M
WHERE M.HomeTeamID = T.TeamID AND (SELECT COUNT HomeGoals > AwayGoals FROM Matches) > (SELECT COUNT AwayGoals > HomeGoals FROM Matches)
but still getting syntax error. Is this the kind of thing you meant, using the SELECT COUNT function within the AND clause?

Comment: @JaneDelaney pls edit the last 2 comments into the question **and format them**.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a sample db of your example and managed to write a query that returns exactly what you asked for. It's a bit complicated, so I'll first show the query and then break it down:

```
SELECT away_query.id, away_query.name, away_query.away_wins, home_query.home_wins
FROM (
    SELECT teams.id, teams.name, count(*) as away_wins
    FROM teams
    JOIN matches ON teams.id = matches.away_team_id AND matches.away_goals>matches.home_goals
    GROUP BY teams.id
) as away_query
JOIN (
    SELECT teams.id, teams.name, count(*) as home_wins
    FROM teams
    JOIN matches ON teams.id = matches.home_team_id AND matches.home_goals>matches.away_goals
    GROUP BY teams.id
) as home_query
ON away_query.id=home_query.id
HAVING away_query.away_wins>home_query.home_wins
```

The first thing I noticed was missing from your SQL is the JOIN clause, which is essential when combining data from several tables.
The first query I wrote is the one that retrieves the number of away wins for each team:

```
SELECT teams.id, teams.name, count(*) as away_wins
FROM teams
JOIN matches ON teams.id = matches.away_team_id AND matches.away_goals>matches.home_goals
GROUP BY teams.id
```

The JOIN is used to combine the teams and matches tables on the id field of the "teams" table, and away_team_id field of the matches table, and filter only matches where the away team won.
The GROUP BY makes it count the away wins per team.

I did the same query for home wins:

```
SELECT teams.id, teams.name, count(*) as home_wins
FROM teams
JOIN matches ON teams.id = matches.home_team_id AND matches.home_goals>matches.away_goals
GROUP BY teams.id
```

Now that I had a query for aways wins of each team, and for home wins, I just needed to combine them and filter by "more away wins than home wins".
I did it using sub queries. The FROM is the away wins query, which is JOINed by the home wins query.
The ON combines the 2 queries on the id field, and all is left now is to filter it with the HAVING clause:

```
HAVING away_query.away_wins>home_query.home_wins
```

The result is the first (very long) query featured in this answer.

Comment: Thanks Royar, I tried this and I'm getting the following error:

Comment: ...Unknown column 'away_query.id' in 'field list'

Comment: Can you try to mimick the tables I created?

Comment: I created a table named "teams" with fields: id, name,
and a table named "matches" with fields: id, home_team_id, away_team_id, home_goals, away_goals.
Also try to insert some sample data into the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone who's interested, I managed to get this to work but I had to create two views for away wins and home wins and use these to query:

```
CREATE VIEW HomeWins (TeamName, HomeWins) 
AS SELECT T.TeamName, COUNT(*) 
FROM Teams T, Matches M 
WHERE M.HomeTeamID = T.TeamID 
AND M.HomeGoals > M.AwayGoals

CREATE VIEW AwayWins (TeamName, AwayWins) 
AS SELECT T.TeamName, COUNT(*) 
FROM Teams T, Matches M 
WHERE M.HomeTeamID = T.TeamID 
AND M.HomeGoals < M.AwayGoals

SELECT A.TeamName 
FROM HomeWins H, Awaywins A 
WHERE H.HomeWins < A.AwayWins 
AND A.TeamName = H.TeamName
```